# matplotlib set_major_formatter taking into account range of values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've written a UI that includes a matplotlib figure.  It shows graphs and I'd like to use engineering notation (exponents that are multiples of 3) on the axes.  Note that I want the powers to be written out (e.g. "123×10⁶", not "123 M", hence not using [EngFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter)).

I can do this with a formatting function (`format_eng`) I wrote many years ago and the `set_major_formatter` & `fmt_x_data` features of matplotlib:

```py
def axes_eng_format(ax, x=True, y=True, **kwargs):
    if x:
        if 'use_si' not in kwargs and 'use_latex' not in kwargs:
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda v, pos: format_eng(v, use_latex=True, **kwargs))
        else:
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda v, pos: format_eng(v, **kwargs))
        ax.fmt_xdata = lambda v: format_eng(v, **kwargs)
    if y:
        if 'use_si' not in kwargs and 'use_latex' not in kwargs:
            ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda v, pos: format_eng(v, use_latex=True, **kwargs))
        else:
            ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda v, pos: format_eng(v, **kwargs))
        ax.fmt_ydata = lambda v: format_eng(v, **kwargs)

axes_eng_format(ax)
```

The formatting function itself shouldn't be relevant to this question (as it is just a dumb formatter that only takes a single parameter and hence cannot consider the range of values), however for reference it is here: https://gist.github.com/abudden/3252252632bd8271c49c886771d8f82d

The [formatters only get two parameters](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter): the value (`v`) and the position on the graph (`pos`).  Using just the value `v` is okay and works, but the 0.5 is rendered as 500×10⁻³.  If the range of values on the major axis is (say) 0 to 700×10⁻³, then that's exactly how I'd like it to be rendered, but if the range of values is (like the second image below) 0 to 3.5, I'd rather it were rendered as 0.5 for consistency with the other values on the axis.

The only way I can think of doing this at the moment is to post-process all the tick values, but that doesn't seem like it would be very robust given the user can zoom in and out etc.

Is there a better way of achieving the effect I'm after?  I'm guessing I can do something with `pos`, but I haven't been able to get my head round what would work.  How should I go about using `pos` to tweak the formatting of a number (or is there a better way)?

Y-axis looks good:

[image]

Y axis looks not-so-good:

[image]

Comment: you haven't added your `format_eng` function to the code above, which seems like it might be critical for your question

Comment: @tmdavison It's quite a long function, but I'll share it when I'm back at a computer. I don't think it's critical though: I want to know how to write a function that will change output depending on the range of values. The existing function just takes one value so there's no way it could work.

Comment: I've added a link to the contents of the `format_eng` function, although I don't think it will help much.  I'm looking for an explanation of how to use `pos` (or an alternative method) to tweak the output and `format_eng` doesn't even take `pos` as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pos` argument is just the number (an integer value) of the tick label that is currently formatted, counting from 0 upwards. So using it for the purpose described wouldn't be useful.

Instead you could use the value range that is currently on display, i.e. the current range of the axis using `xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()` and `ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()`. And pass that to the `format_eng` function. Of course `format_eng` needs to be modified accordingly.

Simple example just considering positive values (respect. the maximum value of the x- and y-axis, instead of the range):

```py
  
def format_eng(number, max_value, places=2, force_exponent=None, use_si=False, use_unicode=False, use_latex=False, return_components=False, strip_zeros=True, unit=None, pos_sign=False):
    if max_value < 10000:
        return number
    # ... add the rest of the formatter function code ...
    # si_lookup = {...}
    # ...
    return result
  
def axes_eng_format(ax, x=True, y=True, **kwargs):
    if x:
        if 'use_si' not in kwargs and 'use_latex' not in kwargs:
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda v, pos: format_eng(v, ax.get_xlim()[1], use_latex=True, **kwargs))
        else:
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda v, pos: format_eng(v, ax.get_xlim()[1], **kwargs))
        ax.fmt_xdata = lambda v: format_eng(v, ax.get_xlim()[1], **kwargs)
    if y:
        if 'use_si' not in kwargs and 'use_latex' not in kwargs:
            ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda v, pos: format_eng(v, ax.get_ylim()[1], use_latex=True, **kwargs))
        else:
            ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda v, pos: format_eng(v, ax.get_ylim()[1], **kwargs))
        ax.fmt_ydata = lambda v: format_eng(v, ax.get_ylim()[1],  **kwargs)
```

Sample plot:

```py
x = np.arange(0, 100, 0.00001)
y = np.sin(0.1 * np.pi * x) + 1
y = y * 10000

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
axes_eng_format(ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

And zooming in:

[image: sample plot 2]

Comment: That would work in isolation, but it's an interactive graph, so if the user then zooms in (like going from the first screenshot above to the second one), then the values won't be formatted properly.  `axes_eng_format` is only run once so can't update when the view updates.

Comment: Now I get your point (I guess). Thanks for clarifying! I update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Ah, using a lambda to get access to the `ax` object.  That's a great idea and I think that will work.  Thank you.